# Concatenation issue when using label in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, concatenation

There is a code part in my program. Lets say buf.Substring(0, 4) is a string which is 326 for that moment in the loop. String buf.Substring(0, 4) is updated in a for loop.

```
if (buf.Substring(0, 4).Equals("GG:"))
{
   label22.Text = buf.Substring(4) + "Z" ;
}
```

This outputs on label22 as:

```
326

Z
```

If you replace it as

```
label22.Text = "Z" + buf.Substring(4);
```

then it concatenates properly as:

```
Z326
```

But I want the output to be:

```
326Z
```

Whatever I tried it dodn't work. I tried concatenating different ways or sizing label width very long ect. What could be the problem here?

Comment: 326 are three characters not 4

Comment: Just trim away the cr lf at the end of that substring _buf.Substring(4).Trim() + "Z" ;_

Comment: trim trick worked thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try trimming the output of buf.Substring(4) like this

```
String output = buf.Substring(4).Trim(new char[] {'\r','\n'});
```

Or just plain Trim() like so

```
String output = buf.Substring(4).Trim();
```